# Creation of directory on linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I was given to create a specific tree directory on ubuntu.Can someone tell me if it's possible to set the parent of an already existing directory on linux?(I mean the parent doesn't exist yet)

Comment: If a directory (other than `/`) exists, it has a parent. You can certainly *move* a directory into another parent directory, though.

Comment: Can I get the result without moving that?I'm just looking for a command to create a directory directly linked to an existing folder as parent

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The only way you can change the parent of a folder is to *move* the folder into a new parent.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p ...
```

> -p, --parents
>   no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Comment: its mkdir.. typo

Answer (score 1):

To make a whole tree use the -p flag like:

`mkdir -p top/middle/bottom`

If you already have `middle/bottom` and you want to push them into `top/middle/bottom` then:

```
#make the top dir
mkdir top
#move middle and bottom into the new directory
mv middle top/
```

Comment: Can I get the result without moving that?I'm just looking  for a command to create a directory directly linked to an existing folder as parent

Comment: Inside the existing (parent folder) create a link ( do `man ln` to see how you can create links )  to the child folder you wish.